# Unable to combine two dataframes in R

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, rbind

I am trying to combine two dataframes using `rbind`. Below are the two dfs

```
ab1

structure(list(Product = c("Black Menthol", "Gold ", "Green ", 
"Red "), `Apr 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, `Gold ` = 3L, 
`Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0", "0.02", "0.07", 
"0.09", "Apr 2017"), class = "factor"), `May 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 3L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0", "0.02", 
"0.07", "0.08", "May 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jun 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 4L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 3L), .Label = c("0", "0.02", 
"0.07", "0.08", "Jun 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jul 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 3L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0", "0.02", 
"0.07", "0.09", "Jul 2017"), class = "factor"), `Aug 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 3L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0", "0.02", 
"0.07", "0.09", "Aug 2017"), class = "factor"), `Sep 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 3L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0", "0.02", 
"0.07", "0.09", "Sep 2017"), class = "factor"), `Oct 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 3L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0", "0.02", 
"0.07", "0.08", "Oct 2017"), class = "factor"), `Nov 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 3L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0", "0.02", 
"0.07", "0.09", "Nov 2017"), class = "factor"), `Dec 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 3L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0", "0.03", 
"0.07", "0.08", "Dec 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jan 2018` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 2L, 
`Gold ` = 3L, `Green ` = 1L, `Red ` = 3L), .Label = c("0", "0.03", 
"0.06", "Jan 2018"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")

ab2

structure(list(Product = c("Black Menthol", "Black Non-Menthol", 
"Green ", "Red "), `Apr 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.02", 
"0.07", "0.17", "0.23", "Apr 2017"), class = "factor"), `May 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.02", 
"0.06", "0.17", "0.24", "May 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jun 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.02", 
"0.07", "0.18", "0.25", "Jun 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jul 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.02", 
"0.06", "0.17", "0.24", "Jul 2017"), class = "factor"), `Aug 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.02", 
"0.06", "0.16", "0.23", "Aug 2017"), class = "factor"), `Sep 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.02", 
"0.06", "0.16", "0.23", "Sep 2017"), class = "factor"), `Oct 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.02", 
"0.07", "0.14", "0.22", "Oct 2017"), class = "factor"), `Nov 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.02", 
"0.08", "0.15", "0.22", "Nov 2017"), class = "factor"), `Dec 2017` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.03", 
"0.09", "0.16", "0.20", "Dec 2017"), class = "factor"), `Jan 2018` = structure(c(`Black Menthol` = 1L, 
`Black Non-Menthol` = 3L, `Green ` = 2L, `Red ` = 4L), .Label = c("0.03", 
"0.08", "0.16", "0.22", "Jan 2018"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below is the code I am using to combine them:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ab3 <- reactive({rbind.data.frame(ab1,ab2)})

ab4<- reactive({ ab3 %>% group_by(`Product`) %>%summarize_all(funs(sum))})
```

When I do this I get the following error : `Evaluation error: ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors`

The output I am tying to get is:

```
  Product Apr.2017 May.2017 Jun.2017 Jul.2017 Aug.2017 Sep.2017 Oct.2017
#  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 Black …     0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04      0.04     0.04     0.04
#2 Black …     0.17     0.17     0.18    0.17      0.16     0.16     0.14
#3 Gold        0.07     0.07     0.08    0.07      0.07     0.07     0.07
#4 Green       0.07     0.06     0.07    0.06      0.06     0.06     0.07
#5 Red         0.32     0.32     0.32    0.330     0.32     0.32     0.3
```

Comment: The `rbind` isn't the problem. It's that you're trying to do `sum()` on a `factor` (categorical) variable in your `ab4 <- ...` step. The equivalent of `"apple" + "orange"`. This is because your first `"Product"` column is not a numeric column.

Comment: So I did try to convert all the factors to numeric  after rbindand couldnt get it working :
`ab3_convert<- 
  #    data.frame(lapply(ab3, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))),
  #                   check.names=F, row.names = rownames(ab3))`

Comment: please use the `ab3()` as this is a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(ab1, ab2) %>%
    group_by(Product) %>%
    summarise_all(sum)
## A tibble: 5 x 9
#  Product Apr.2017 May.2017 Jun.2017 Jul.2017 Aug.2017 Sep.2017 Oct.2017
#  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 Black …     0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04      0.04     0.04     0.04
#2 Black …     0.17     0.17     0.18    0.17      0.16     0.16     0.14
#3 Gold        0.07     0.07     0.08    0.07      0.07     0.07     0.07
#4 Green       0.07     0.06     0.07    0.06      0.06     0.06     0.07
#5 Red         0.32     0.32     0.32    0.330     0.32     0.32     0.3
## ... with 1 more variable: Nov.2017 <dbl>
```

This assumes that `ab1` and `ab2` have the same column structure.

---

### Sample data

```
ab1 <- read.table(text =
    "        Product 'Apr 2017' 'May 2017' 'Jun 2017' 'Jul 2017' 'Aug 2017' 'Sep 2017' 'Oct 2017' 'Nov 2017'
1 'Black Menthol'     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02
2         Gold      0.07     0.07     0.08     0.07     0.07     0.07     0.07     0.07
3        Green         0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
4          Red      0.09     0.08     0.07     0.09     0.09     0.09     0.08     0.09
", header = T)
ab2 <- read.table(text =
    "            Product 'Apr 2017' 'May 2017' 'Jun 2017' 'Jul 2017' 'Aug 2017' 'Sep 2017' 'Oct 2017' 'Nov 2017'
1     'Black Menthol'     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02
2 'Black Non-Menthol'     0.17     0.17     0.18     0.17     0.16     0.16     0.14     0.15
3            Green      0.07     0.06     0.07     0.06     0.06     0.06     0.07     0.08
4              Red      0.23     0.24     0.25     0.24     0.23     0.23     0.22     0.22
", header = T)
```

---

### Update

To address the `factor` issue: Convert all columns except `Product` to `numeric` before binding rows.

```
bind_rows(
    ab1 %>% mutate_at(vars(-Product), function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))),
    ab2 %>% mutate_at(vars(-Product), function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))) %>%
    group_by(Product) %>%
    summarise_all(sum)
## A tibble: 5 x 11
#  Product `Apr 2017` `May 2017` `Jun 2017` `Jul 2017` `Aug 2017` `Sep 2017`
#  <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 Black …       0.04       0.04       0.04      0.04        0.04       0.04
#2 Black …       0.17       0.17       0.18      0.17        0.16       0.16
#3 "Gold "       0.07       0.07       0.08      0.07        0.07       0.07
#4 "Green…       0.07       0.06       0.07      0.06        0.06       0.06
#5 "Red "        0.32       0.32       0.32      0.330       0.32       0.32
## ... with 4 more variables: `Oct 2017` <dbl>, `Nov 2017` <dbl>, `Dec
##   2017` <dbl>, `Jan 2018` <dbl>
```

Comment: yes but the problem is my dfs which I am using are derived from other part and it has all the columns as factors.

Comment: Now that I look again, if you `group_by(Product)` you shouldn't have to exclude it from the `summarize_all` function. OP has something else stuffing this up.

Comment: @thelatemail Yeah there is something else going on. I'm using `summarise_at` instead of `summarise_all` here though, so I need to exclude `Product`. From OPs comment it seems that all columns containing numbers are in fact `factor`s. Strange.

Comment: @SNT Please edit your post to include the `dput` of `ab1` and `ab2`. A lot of these discussions can be avoided if you provide sample data in a form that clearly states data types.

Comment: @MauritsEvers This is error I get when I do `rbind` : `Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument.`

Comment: @SNT That's not what I asked. Please edit your post to include `dput(ab1)` and `dput(ab2)`. Also do you get the same error when using `bind_rows`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Is that what you meant by `dput`

Comment: @SNT Yes, thanks. I've updated my answer. You need to convert all columns except `Product` to `numeric` via `as.numeric(as.character(...))` *prior* to binding rows.